# BootStrap: With 5 Modal Forms on a page. How to check with JavaScript/jQuery which one is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 5 modal forms in a page. And I want to get the Id of the currently opened one.

I know I can check with `$('#myModal').hasClass('in');`. If I have 5 modal forms I have to write this 5 times. Which I don't want to.

Is there some way I can determine which modal the user has open currently open and then I will get the id of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `shown.bs.modal` event to get the current open modal.

[**Modal Events**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

> **shown.bs.modal**
>
> This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete). If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.

Here is an example

```js
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var crntModalId = "current modal id is: " + $(this).attr('id');
  $('.output').text('');
  $('.output').text(crntModalId);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="output"></div>

<br>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-One">
  Launch modal one
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-One" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-Two">
  Launch modal two
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-Two" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, with [bootstrap modal event's](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

To get any `attribute value` from the modal trigger button you can use `$(e.relatedTarget)`

To get the modal `attribute value` you can use `$(e.currentTarget)`

In your case, you can get the `Opened modal id` with

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var modalid = $(e.currentTarget).attr('id');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20b7q67k/3/)

Answer (score 0):

A bootstrap modal gets automatically the class 'shown.bs.modal' when is open, so you can use this to track which one is open.